# Как мне сделать обработку баланса? RedBeanPHP

Tags: php

Начало кода.

```
<?php 
require "db.php";
$user = R::findOne('users', 'id = ?', array($_SESSION['user']->id));
?>
```

Вывожу баланс:

```
<?php echo $user->balance;?>
```

Как сделать, что бы при нажатии на кнопку, баланс становился меньше, на указанную сумму. Так же что бы было обновление в бд.

[image: База данных:]

Comment: Надо выучить программирование, HTML, HTTP, SQL. И после этого будет ясно, как сделать обработку баланса

Comment: Я тут зарегался что бы помогли, а не такое писали.

Comment: Через html вы покажете кнопку, через клик на кнопку пошлете запрос (например, через ajax) на сервер с вашим php кодом, где используя RedBeanPHP поменяете у указанного юзера поле баланса и сохраните (выполнив sql запрос) его в базе

Comment: К сожалению, посмотреть видео про редбин и зарегаться на стаковерфлоу недостаточно, чтобы разрабатывать сайты